# Are humans Summonable?

Tags: harry-potter

In [this comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/82447/why-didnt-anybody-summon-the-triwizard-cup-in-the-maze#comment176964_82447), the question was raised: **Are humans Summonable?**

In the Triwizard Tournament, Harry Potter summons his broom.

In the second task, none of the contestants even attempt to summon the hostages. Is this because a human is un-Summonable?

I don't have my book right now, but Harry Potter attempts to Summon Rubeus Hagrid in the Battle of Seven Potters. However, as Hagrid did not come shooting towards him, the spell didn't work. But, Hagrid is half-giant.

We also see, in The Goblet of Fire, that Harry Summoned a fly. (Although it is mentioned that maybe the fly was just stupid, and that maybe the spell didn't work, and that it was a coincidence.)

**Does 'Accio' work on a human being?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the rules and limits of \*accio\* spell?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24713/what-are-the-rules-and-limits-of-accio-spell)

Comment: @EvdzhanMustafa: No, this is asking whether it works on a human specifically.

Comment: In the possible dupe question, the accepted answer states that you can Accio living creatures. Harry uses the spell on a toad during Potions Class in OOTP. But it's not explicitly stated for humans. If it's also possible on humans, which seems logical, it is probably very hard due to their weight. But no canon sources that I know of.

Comment: Harry did attempt Accio on Hagrid in DH.

Comment: @EvdzhanMustafa Yes he did, as OP mentioned in his question. However Hagrid is quite heavy since he's half giant and he was out of sight which makes Accio harder to perform in a stress situation I think. So it's still not quite clear if it's possible on humans.