# Why was Harry able to Accio the Cup portkey in GOF

Tags: harry-potter

In GOF the Tri-Wizard cup was a port key that takes Harry to the graveyard with Voldemort.

Aside from the fact that it then takes him back to Hogwarts when he did so he used the Accio spell to bring the cup to him in the graveyard.

Assuming that this shouldnt be possible during the tournemant otherwise any one of the participants could have simply used the spell to instantly win the Cup.

How did this then work in the graveyard ?

Comment: I think of it as this: The tournament was over after Harry touched the cup the first time.  Technically he had won already before he was taken to the graveyard.  So any enchantments on the cup for the tournament could have been taken off the moment he touched it the first time.

Comment: technically, this is looking at this from the opposite angle, but i think this is largely covered in [Why didn't anybody Summon the Triwizard cup in the maze?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/82447/5184) and [What are the rules and limits of Accio spell?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/24713/5184)

Comment: Or..... There wasn't an anti-Accio spell cast on the Cup. There is no mention in the books that the cup was anti-accio charmed. He just tried and it worked

Comment: Possibly the area around the cup was accio protected?

Comment: @Ummdustry highly unlikely. Fake Mad-eye (Barty Jr.) wanted Harry to get through; he would never put enchantments around the cup.