# Are students required to attend Quidditch matches?

Tags: harry-potter, quidditch

Given that students from all houses attend Quidditch matches, whether their house is playing or not, can it be concluded that matches are compulsory for students? In The Half Blood Prince, Harry says goodbye to Ron in the hospital wing and leaves for the match:

> He hurried through the deserted corridors; the whole school was outside, either already seated in the stadium or heading down toward it.

'The whole school' could be an exaggeration for the sake of simplicity. Harry then runs into Malfoy, who is 'skulking off' when the match is about to start. It's unclear if Harry's suspicion is only because he is already wary of Malfoy, or if leaving a match is not allowed.

Apart from being bedridden or having detention, are students allowed to skip matches simply because they've chosen not to?

Comment: As far as why essentially everybody attends if it isn't compulsory goes: what else is there to do at a boarding school when the vast majority of your friends are at said game?

Comment: You can sit for a few hours in dubious weather while players chuck balls around and crash into each other on brooms... OR you can explore a magical haunted castle that has a kitchen full of snacks, an extensive library, exciting death traps, and countless opportunities for mischief.

Comment: That's just school though, by the time you live there - it's boring by default.

Comment: ...according to the Maurader's Map shown in the film...there are.....other things people could be doing as well

Comment: @creative-username When you're a wizard there's nothing special about a "magical haunted castle" (muggleborns would be an exception to this, of course).

Comment: @Wipqozn There’s nothing that special about Quidditch either.

Comment: @creative-username you could say that about any sport, to be honest.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

All signs point to inter-school Quidditch matches being ***voluntary to attend***, but also extremely popular, to the point where attendance is pretty much essential, from a social perspective.

> ‘Stop worrying, Oliver,’ said Alicia soothingly, ‘we don’t mind a bit
> of rain.’
>
> But it was considerably more than a bit of rain. **Such was the
> popularity of Quidditch that the whole school turned out to watch the
> match as usual,** but they ran down the lawns towards the Quidditch
> pitch, heads bowed against the ferocious wind, umbrellas being whipped
> out of their hands as they went. Just before he entered the changing
> room, Harry saw Malfoy, Crabbe and Goyle laughing and pointing at him
> from under an enormous umbrella on their way to the stadium.
>
> <sub><sup>*Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban*</sup></sub>

---

Malfoy is notable in his absence on at least two occasions. The crowd is described as comprising 'the rest of the school'

> “Yeah … well, I saw Malfoy sneaking off with a couple of girls who didn’t look like they wanted to be with him, and that’s the second time he’s made sure he isn’t down on the Quidditch pitch with the rest of the school. He skipped the last match too, remember?’ Harry sighed.”
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince</sup></sub>

---

On at least one occasion Hermione (who else?) skips a match so that she can use her free period for (what else?) additional study (where else?) in the library.

> “But why’s she got to go to the library?’
> ‘Because that’s what Hermione does,’ said Ron, shrugging. ‘When in doubt, go to the library.’
> Harry stood, irresolute, trying to catch the voice again, but people were now emerging from the Great Hall behind him, talking loudly, exiting through the front doors on their way to the Quidditch pitch.
> ‘You’d better get moving,’ said Ron. ‘It’s nearly eleven – the match.”
>
> *Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*

There appears to be **no restriction on her doing so and no punishment for having done so**.

Comment: Given that Hermione is usually a stickler for school rules, that is very solid evidence. And such a Hermione thing to do!

Comment: @creative-username - She breaks the school rules regularly, typically to help her friends.

Comment: Yes, true. And this was the same year she brewed illicit Polyjuice. But she is usually  conscious of the fact that they're breaking rules and reminds Ron and Harry of it often, even when it's because they're figuring out how to break those same rules. Maybe 'stickler' wasn't a great word choice.

Comment: @creative-username you may want to read [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/105995/98028) (the top answer notably) about Hermione's respect of rules. After that you will put "respect" between quotation marks :-)

Comment: @Jenayah Even that question states "Generally, Hermione is a prim character who appreciates rules and regulations." which I completely agree with. Hermione has respect for rules but understands there are times when they must be broken. Both are true.

Comment: Is it so clear that Hermione was skipping the match? The match hadn't even started yet when McGonagall canceled it - Hermione had by that point already left the library, been attacked, been brought to the Hospital Wing, etc. It seems like she may have just intended a slight detour on the way to the match.

Comment: @Valorum - that's...different. Breaking rules to help friends is...not really "breaking" rules...it's just, errm...applying the metarules which require us to assist our friends and snitch on our enemies and not get caught. Especially the latter... And besides, Dumbledore certainly knows all about whatever goes on in the castle. Which makes it OK. Probably...

Answer (score 4):

The question here seems to combine two separate things: 1. Is attending Quidditch matches compulsory? 2. Did anyone ever skip Quidditch simply of their own choice?

I think we can infer that Quidditch attendance is not mandatory from the fact that in Chapter Twenty-Four of *Half-Blood Prince* Harry has detention during a Quidditch match:

> "Well, we shall see how you feel after your detentions," said Snape. "Ten o'clock Saturday morning, Potter. My office."
>
> "But sir..." said Harry, looking up desperately. "Quidditch... the last match of the..."
>
> "Ten o'clock," whispered Snape, with a smile that showed his yellow teeth. "Poor Gryffindor... fourth place this year, I fear..."

Given that we never find detentions occurring during mandatory student activities, it would seem to be reasonable to conclude that attendance at Quidditch matches was not, in fact, mandatory.

As for whether anyone ever ditched a Quidditch match of their own volition, Harry himself did this in Chapter Thirty of *Order of the Phoenix*:

> “Listen,” he whispered, “can yeh come with me? Now?
>   While ev’ryone’s watchin’ the match?”
>
> “Er... can’t it wait, Hagrid?” asked Harry. “Till the
>   match is over?
>
> “No,” said Hagrid. “No, Harry, it’s gotta be now...
>   while ev’ryone’s lookin’ the other way... Please?”
>
> Hagrid’s nose was gently dripping blood. His eyes
>   were both blackened. Harry had not seen him this
>   close up since his return to the school; he looked
>   utterly woebegone.
>
> “’Course,” said Harry at once, “’course we’ll come...”

There are some implications over the following pages that they are doing something they shouldn't be doing. For example:

> “I ’ppreciate this, you two, I really do,” said Hagrid as
>   they reached the stairs. He kept looking around
>   nervously as they descended toward the lawn below.
>   “I jus’ hope she doesn’ notice us goin’...”

And:

> “Yeah,” said Hagrid. “C’mon now, quick, before we’re
>   spotted!”

And:

> “Look — there’s people
>   comin’ out already — if you two hurry yeh’ll be able ter blend in with the crowd an’ no one’ll know you
>   weren’t there!”

But this may not be because missing Quidditch itself is problematic, but that the specific nature of what they were doing instead was problematic.

Comment: You're right, there were two questions there. I edited the last bit to clarify what's being asked.

Comment: There are multiple examples of students being ordered (by teacher) to do things that would otherwise breach a school rule. Being outdoor after hours for detentions, for example

Comment: @Valorum It's only against the rules to be outdoors after hours when you don't have permission to be outdoors. Much like one is not breaking any rule by being in the Restricted Section with permission. The rule is simply not applicable to that situation. My argument wasn't that teachers can't allow (or force) students to do things that would otherwise be against the rules. My argument was that detentions never take place during mandatory activities.

Comment: @Alex - Being inside after curfew *is* a mandatory activity

Comment: @Valorum There’s no activity “be inside after curfew” just like there’s no activity of “don’t be in the Forbidden Forest” or “don’t be in the third floor corridor”. A mandatory activity is something specific that has to be done; the reason why detentions don’t overlap these is that then those activities would not be completed. There is nothing that needs to be completed by being inside after curfew, and thus there is nothing lost if detention occurs then.

Comment: I don't think the OotP example really is because of a supposed rule you need to attend the Quidditch matches. I think this is more likely because Harry and Ron both really like Quidditch, and the fact that they're visiting a known associate of Dumbledore instead of the Quidditch match, when Dumbledore at this point was under heavy scrutiny from the Ministry and their psychotoady Umbridge, would be really suspicious, especially when this associate is injured from an unsanctioned and probably illegal diplomatic mission to a magical species.

Comment: @Nzall Hence the last paragraph.