# Is there a "reverse-Accio" spell?

Tags: harry-potter, spells

Is there a complementary return-to-where-it-was spell that can be used after the Accio spell has been used? For example, Harry Accios his broom from his closet in GoF to help him retrieve the dragon egg. After the event was over, could Harry have "un-Accioed" his broom to return it to his closet to save him the trouble of carrying it back up to his room? Or to help Hermione surreptitiously put the Horcrux books back in Dumbledore's hiding spot in DH?

The SQL comments in [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/24713/54605) inspired my question here.

Comment: There is `Mobiliarbus` (move object) and `Wingardium Leviosa` (fly/move object).

Comment: @Zoredache - Do they require line of sight?

Comment: I think what you mean is "reverse-Accio", and not "un-Accio". At least based on what I read in your question. Also, _Locomotor_ could be used for what you need.

Comment: There was also the _handwaving_ that Dumbledore performed in Slughorn's temporary home. Seemed to put everything in place, even though there was a lot of stuff, and Dumbledore had no idea of the original configuration. Yet, it is more of a *fix* than *send back* spell.

Comment: @Gallifreyan - What's the difference between *Locomotor* and the two mentioned by Zoredache?

Comment: @iMerchant - `Mobiliarbus` seems to be just for trees. `Wingardium Leviosa` seems to be for making objects fly/levitate. `Locomotor` seems to be for moving objects via levitation.

Comment: Mobiliarbus only works on plants and wooden objects. Wingardium leviosa requires concentration and wand gestures to move the object.
Locomotor would be an enchantment where the object remains enchanted without uninterrupted concentration, like accio.

Comment: @RedOculus - Mobiliarbus only appears over in canon, where it moves a tree, and the spell translates to "move tree". Thus I can understand thinking that it may be specific to trees, but on what basis are you generalizing that it's for "plants and wooden objects"?

Comment: This source says wooden objects
http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Mobiliarbus#cite_note-0

Comment: That is not what a `return` statement does. Not even close.

Comment: @RedOculus - The general consensus is that the movies aren't to be used as canon unless the OP specifically asks for it.

Comment: `Put that thing back where it came from or so help me!`

Answer (score 44, accepted):

## Yes, the Banishing charm.

We see Harry, Ron, and Hermione practicing this spell in GoF:

> They were supposed to be practicing **the opposite of the Summoning Charm today** — the Banishing Charm. Owing to the potential for nasty accidents when objects kept flying across the room, Professor Flitwick had given each student a stack of cushions on which to practice, the theory being that these wouldn’t hurt anyone if they went off target. It was a good theory, but it wasn’t working very well.
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*, chapter 26: The Second Task</sub>

It appears that the object goes to where you direct it:

> "I just want to know what Snape did with his first chance, if he's already on his second one," said Harry grimly, and his cushion, to his very great surprise, flew straight across the room and landed neatly on top of Hermione's.
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*, chapter 26: The Second Task</sub>

Apparently the incantation is *Depulso*, as revealed in the [video game adaption of *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban*](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Banishing_Charm), but that depends on your canon level.

Comment: But what's the _spell_?

Comment: @Gallifreyan - not revealed in the book what the incantation is.

Comment: http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Talk:Banishing_Charm

Comment: @Gallifreyan - I never watched any of the movies except for TSS and TCoS, and FBAWTFT. Never played video games either.

Comment: "Depulso" is the incantation, Depulso sends both objects and living things away from the caster. I'm unable to find any instance of an object going further than across the room.

Comment: furthermore, a counter-charm is specifically designed to undo or prevent the effects of an another spell. Depulso may counter the effects of Accio by repelling the object, but doesn't necessarily put it back where it was.

Comment: @RedOculus ...neither does Locomotor. But the Banishing charm is *specifically* said to be the opposite of Accio, so...

Comment: @Mithrandir Evidence says otherwise. Piertotum, leg-locker, and jelly legs are all locomotor spells. Each one has a lasting effect after the spell is cast without need for further concentration. Lets compare the spell effects; Locomotor, causes the named object to rise in the air and move around at the will of the caster. The Banishing charm sends objects away from the caster. key phrase here is "at the will of the caster." What if harry banished his broom and he was between the broom and it's destination? It wouldn't be moving away from the caster as the spell says, it would move to him..

Answer (score 8):

***Locomotor*** - The spell causes the named object to rise in the air and move around **at the will of the caster**

An example of use is when Flitwick used "Locomotor trunks" to move Trelawney's belongings back up the main staircase to her lodgings:

> Professor Sprout came hurrying forward out of the crowd and grabbed Professor Trelawney's other arm. Together they guided her past Umbridge and up the marble stairs. Professor Flitwick went scurrying after them, his wand held out before him; he squeaked, "*Locomotor trunks!*" and Professor Trelawney's luggage rose into the air and proceeded up the staircase after her, Professor Flitwick bringing up the rear.
>   <sub>*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*, chapter 26: Seen and Unforseen</sub>

Comment: So could've Harry used *Locomotor* to send his broom back to his closet from the arena after capturing the dragon egg? In other words, send it on its way and let the broom figure out how to navigate across Hogwarts grounds and inside the building and into his room.

Comment: Although Cannon sources don't say so specifically, there is good evidence to suggest the object does know where to go upon casting. When McGonagall used Piertotum Locomotor to animate the statues and suits of armor, they moved into formation without directions from the caster.

Comment: Isn't the case with the statues a special case? She does say that Hogwarts will defend itself so the statues must have some kind of direction ; that was the way I interpreted the passage (like from a previous enchantment or something). I suppose it begs the question: do enchanted or animated objects have the ability to go to places on their own accord?

Comment: Piertotum locomotor is one of several off shoots to the locomotor spell. Others include locomotor mortis and wibbly. The commonality in all locomotor spells is that the object or person remains enchanted after the spell is cast, without further concentration. The statues are animated by Piertotem locomotor but the act autonomously afterword.

Comment: @user28875 it doesn't "beg the question" since that's circular logic. it "raises the question."